# Values of some variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

At the beginning w and c equals 0 but the problem is when I change the value of w for instance with the scale widget and then I change the value of c the value of w go back to 0.

How can I solve it this ?

Here is my code :

```
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

app = tk.Tk()
app.wm_title("Tools")

def updateScale(value):
   ax.clear()
   print "scale is now %s" % (value)
   ax.plot(m, np.exp(m))
   a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
   w = float(value)
   b = w*a+c
   ax.plot(a,b)
   graph.show()
   return w

def updateScale1(value1):
   ax.clear()
   print "scale is now %s" % (value1)
   ax.plot(m, np.exp(m))
   a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
   c = float(value1)
   b = w*a+c
   ax.plot(a,b)
   graph.show()
   return c

fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=96)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#bx = fig.add_subplot(111)
m = np.array([1,2,3])
ax.plot(m,np.exp(m))

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
c = 0
w = 0
b = w * a + c
ax.plot(a,b)

graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=app)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan = 11, padx =10, pady =5)

value = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale(app, variable=value, orient="horizontal",length = 100, from_=0.55, to=2.75, resolution = 0.01,command=updateScale)
scale.grid(row=0, column=1)


value1 = tk.DoubleVar()
scale1 = tk.Scale(app, variable=value1, orient="horizontal", command=updateScale1)
scale1.grid(row=1, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The trouble is that in `updateScale()` you assign to `w`, but not `c` and in `updateScale1()` you assign to `c` but not `w`.

Comment: How can I solve this ? I thought to add an argument to updateScale and updateScale1 ? What do you think of this ?

Comment: I tried to put 2 arguments in updateScale and updateScale1 but it does not work... :/

Answer (score 0):

It's because update functions use the non-updated values of `c` and `w`. There are probably better ways of doing this but try adding:

```
global c, w
```

in each update function definition.

Your outermost scope has the variables `c` and `w` but the variables `c` and `w` in the functions are completely different variables as they're neither children of your outerscope nor are the variables explicitly passed into them.